# uppercase to tittle() using RegEx

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to find all uppercased words in text and make them titled. I've been trying to do this using re.sub but I can't figure out what the second argument should be. I tried:

```
import re

text = """
This is SOME text that I HAVE to change
I hope it WOULD work pretty EASY"""

pattern = r'(?P<b>[A-Z])(?P<a>[A-Z]+)'

re.sub(pattern, pattern.title(), text)

print(text)
```

I guess I need to pass the match object as the second argument but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

text = """This is SOME text that I HAVE to change
I hope it WOULD work pretty EASY"""
pattern = r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b'
text = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().title(), text)
print(text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IhbBsO) yielding

```
This is Some text that I Have to change
I hope it Would work pretty Easy
```

The [`\b[A-Z]{2,}\b` regex](https://regex101.com/r/5atjPO/1) matches any 2 or more uppercase ASCII letters within word boundaries (as a whole word). Within the lambda expression, the match value is accessed using `m.group()` and it is returned as the replacement after being modified with the `title()` method.

Comment: Why not just use `+`?

Comment: @Olivier Because the OP intent is to only process 2+ letter  words.

Comment: Sure, just pointing out that it changes nothing, since you would match already capitalized one-letter words